# ionic - change path of index.html

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework

I have used the generator of app `ionic start myApp blank` as a start point.

But now I have special requirements of code's structure.
I must place in a same group the resource of the same type.

- **js directory** for just js files
- **html directory** for html files

and so on...

The problem here is index.html, I must move it from www directory to www/html directory, how can I achieve it?

Comment: You will have to make change in native files where index.html file's path is specified.